# PHP not returning results from MySQL query as expected

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm trying to create a variable which is dependent on some information from the database. I'm trying to generate a `$path` variable which stores a path, depending on what information is recovered from the database.

```
$linkid = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db("table", $linkid);
$variable = "00001";
$groupID = null;
$temp = mysql_query("SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='$variable'", $linkid);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($temp)){
    global $groupID;
    foreach ($row as $field){
        $groupID = $field;
    }
}

....

$path = "C:\WAMP\www\project\\" . $groupID;
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die('Unable to open $path');
```

The idea behind this is that `$variable` is set before the PHP is run, however it's set to `00001` for testing. The ideal situation is that `$path` should equal `C:\WAMP\www\project\00001\`. Currently, when I `echo` back the `$path` all I get is the original path without the `$groupID` added to the end.

I also receive the message "mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource" but I've used this method for retrieving information before and it worked just fine, and I set up my table in the same way so I don't think the issue is there.

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious, so any help is appreciated. It's not for an assignment or anything school related (just trying stuff out to learn more) so knock yourselves out with correcting it and explaining why :)

In addition, only one `memberID` will ever be a match to the `$variable`, so if there's an alternative way to fetch it I'd appreciate knowing.

Oh, and I know my variable names are shocking but they're only that on here, on my actual code they're different so no criticism please :p

**EDIT:** The SQL query is correct, after following BT634's advice and when running it on phpMyAdmin I get the groupID I want and expect.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that - my tutor at uni in the PHP module I had last term used that as the 'norm' for MySQL. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: @Dagon You only see it _ten_ times a day?

Comment: Do you have a `memberID` equal to `00001` in your table? What if you `var_dump($groupID)`, is it still null or sth else?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i've had to cut back on my S.O use, the guy who pays me is complaining  i write more code on S.O than for him

Comment: 3 times in the last hour @j0k, please give it a rest.

Comment: @j0k Yeah I have a memberID equal to it (currently only have one member just to sort this out). And yeah, it is null.

Comment: does mysql_result($temp,0) return anything?

Comment: @CJZiegler Same error as the one I put in the OQ.

Comment: @Dagon the problem is, the mysql_* comment almost always gets upvoted. It's cheap reputation.

Comment: @JonHulka i plan to post my 'compliant' about it every time I see it, to see if 2 wrongs do make right.

Comment: @Dagon I think comments should be down-votable. You might get a few upvotes for complaining about it though ;)

Comment: @Zackehh9lives There is something that i can't understand! why did you use a `foreach` loop that actually it doesn't do anything and value of `$groupID` will be equal to the last value of `$field` :?

Comment: @JonHulka I don't see how people can gain reputation from getting upvoted from a comment. And if you think my comment isn't appropriate, you can still flag it ;)

Comment: oh guys, please stop that!

Comment: @MustafaShujaie Because I dunno another way to do it, I've never dealt with only one value before :P and hopefully $groupID will be equal, but for some reason it isn't!

Comment: @j0k my mistake, I thought upvotes to comments gave reputation as well.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives you can use `$field['column']` without using foreach

Comment: @Zackehh9lives make sure your column names are correct. I got the error you got all because my column name was wrong in my where clause.

Comment: @CJZiegler I ran it through on phpMyAdmin and it returned the correct groupID, although I did `where memberID=00001` as opposed to the variable. Perhaps my variable is incorrect?

Comment: Note that the `global $groupID;` can go at the start of your code - this operates in the same "space" as the rest of the code, so there's no need to put it in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're not specifying what **database** to connect to in your connection - you're specifying what **table**. You might also want to check how many rows your query is returning:

```
$temp = mysql_query("SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='$variable'", $linkid);
echo mysql_num_rows($temp);
```

If it's still complaining about `$temp` not being a valid resource, change your MySQL connection code to:

```
// Establish connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

// Make your query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='$variable'");

// Find out what the value of the query is (i.e. what object/resource it is)
var_dump($result);
```

---

Once you know that MySQL is returning valid data, extract the values you want. You don't have to use globals:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($temp)){
    $groupId = $row[0];
}

// Use $groupId however you please...
```

One thing to bear in mind is that [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) will return

```
array
(
   0 => '...'
)
```

Whilst [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) will return:

```
array
(
   'groupId' => '...'
)
```

Comment: Top chunk doesn't help, and the bottom chunk returns `boolean false`

Comment: If your `mysql_query` variable returns false you need to adjust your connection parameters. Make sure you're connecting to the right DB. Include the die command to output any MySQL errors.

Comment: It's now returning `resource(4, mysql result)`

Comment: I'm getting an undefined index for groupID, yet I can clearly see that it exists on the table. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see when you do `print_r($row)` in the while loop?

Comment: Sorry, look at my updated answer. Your index needs to be '0' rather than 'groupID'

Comment: This works! Thanks, I have my path sorted out using your answer! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_select_db("table", $linkid)
```

should actually be

```
mysql_select_db("database_name", $linkid)
```

since you are connecting to the database that contains the table and not the table itself.

Also, try `mysql_result($temp,0)` instead of the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Find out what query it's *definitely* running, and paste that into a normal MySQL client to make sure your query is correct.

Just do this after defining "$variable"

```
exit("SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='$variable'");
```

Then copy the output into a MySQL client (or MySQL from the command line).

Comment: Just done it, it's equal to `SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='00001'` and running it in phpMyAdmin gets the correct groupID.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
global $groupID;

$linkid = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db("table", $linkid);
$variable = "00001";
$groupID = null;
$sql = "SELECT groupID FROM table WHERE memberID='$variable'";
$temp = mysql_query($sql, $linkid) or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_row($temp);
if ($row) {
    $groupID = $row['groupID'];
}
```

If you are retrieving a single value, and it is guaranteed to be unique, then the loop structures are unnecessary. I've added a check to ensure the query exits with an error if there's a problem - it is ideal to do this everywhere, so for example do it with `mysql_select_db` too.